# ClickOnce is it a good WIndows installer for an invisible installation?

Tags: windows, installation, clickonce, windows-installer

Is [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) a viable technology for a software that wants to be installed in Windows, from all browsers, as invisibly as possible (I want to minimize, or completely remove, the "Do you want to save file", "Do you want to run this file", etc)?

Will ClickOnce only install from IE, or is it supported by Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc?

Comment: No, this is not for a virus. I just want to make the installation as user-friendly as possible.

Comment: So far as I am aware the only browser support for ClickOne is in IE and Firefox. The Firefox support is via a Firefox extension supplied by MS. There are a variety of other extensions for other browsers but they are not widely deployed, e.g. [ClickOnce for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl). I'm not actually sure what happens with ClickOnce on a non-supported browser. Perhaps the user just downloads an exe and then runs that themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For guaranteed installation, a use must install a ClickOnce application through Internet Explorer 6 or higher.  Also, the user will need Microsoft Windows Installer.  (I'm having a tough time quickly finding which version of the MS Installer is required, but if the user has purchased their PC within the last 6, or so, years, they will be fine.)

Yes, ClickOnce can still be installed through Firefox and Chrome, however, they will have to go and search for a plug-in or extension and install that, first, before installing your software.  In my case, I test for the user's browser using JavaScript.  If they are using anything but Internet Explorer, I hide the installation instructions and links, and prompt them to return from within IE.

In regards to your comments, it is also worth mentioning that ClickOnce isn't 'invisible'.  The user will need to click at least two buttons.  One to start the download and another which always pops up in regards to application security.  They could have to click through a couple more screens if you have to bundle any prerequisite software.  At a minimum, most pre-requisites require the clicking of an `Accept` button to a EULA.